# can't get ggplot bars to stack

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to get these `chickwt$feed` bars to stack on top of each other. But every example I find online has two separate `aes()` *x* and *fill* values. Mine happen to be the same based on my data frame. This seems to prevent stacking. So how do I get the bars to stack in one column, adding up to 100%?

And I'd also like the name of each section of the bar displayed centered in said category.

```
library(tidyverse)
chickpct <- chickwts %>% 
  group_by(feed) %>% 
  mutate(count = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(percent = count / n()) %>% 
  group_by(feed) %>% 
  summarize(percent = mean(percent))

ggplot(chickpct, aes(x = feed, y = percent, fill = feed)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a new column with an uniform label, map that column to `x`.

```
library(tidyverse)
chickpct <- chickwts %>% 
  group_by(feed) %>% 
  mutate(count = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(percent = count / n()) %>% 
  group_by(feed) %>% 
  summarize(percent = mean(percent)) %>%
  mutate(Feed = "Feed")

ggplot(chickpct, aes(x = Feed, y = percent, fill = feed)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  xlab("")
```

[image]

Add labels to each bar chunk.

```
library(tidyverse)
chickpct <- chickwts %>% 
  group_by(feed) %>% 
  mutate(count = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(percent = count / n()) %>% 
  group_by(feed) %>% 
  summarize(percent = mean(percent)) %>%
  mutate(Feed = "Feed") %>%
  mutate(feed = factor(feed, levels = rev(levels(feed)))) %>%
  mutate(Y = cumsum(percent),
         Y2 = Y - percent/2)

ggplot(chickpct, aes(x = Feed, y = percent, fill = feed)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_label(aes(y = Y2, label = feed)) +
  xlab("") +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. and how do I remove the legend and get the `feed` to be displayed on the actual chart, centered in each color band?

Comment: You can add using `geom_text(aes(label = feed, vjust = 0))`